# Perform alter for many tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have many tables, which names start with `Lookup_`. How can I alter column `Name` in every such table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want to do with Name, but this is how you change it to nvarchar(20).

```
Declare @sql as nvarchar(500)
Declare TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 'alter table ' + table_schema + '.'+ table_name +' alter column name nvarchar(20)' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE left(table_name, 7) = 'lookup_' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
INTO @sql
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     EXEC (@sql)
     FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
     INTO @sql
END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: AndriyM while writing this query i was wondering about how else i could check for the tablename. Thx for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

this looks much better

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 
    @command1 = 'alter table ? alter column name nvarchar(20)'
    , @whereand = 'and left(o.name, 7) = ''lookup_'' and o.type = ''U'''
```